# Dashboard Development Steps

Tags: dashboard, project-planning

I come up with a quite broad questions after reading many different discussions on the dashboard build.
What is the usual development steps to develop a dashboard, from sketching to releasing to the public?
Mainly is the planning steps/phases, I feel.
It is quite broad questoin, general mindset would be very helpful.

Thanks.